# JS split advanced (i think)

Tags: javascript, split

Can anyone help me?
I want to split a hex string on "0000", but this "0000" must be followed by anything other than "00". I'm trying to Split (), but any solution serves me.

EDIT: Explaining ... and correcting a few things: P

This is an example of hexstring I'm using.
http://pastebin.com/u68bG6PP (It is a coded text in Shift-JIS (with some peculiarities example below))

"82824f4f00000000828250500000000082825151000000008282525200000000828253530000000082825454000000008282555500000000"

Here "0000" indicates that is the end of the text line, so it should be split in the last "0000" before the next line (which never begins with "00").

Basically necessary that the above excerpt turn:

82824f4f0000
828250500000
828251510000
828252520000
828253530000
828254540000
828255550000

And that, I hope the explanation is good now ee.

And extra question, I never really touched with Shift_JIS, so any way to turn it into unicode for displaying, or simply display it as SJIS is welcome.

Comment: Provide sample input and what you've tried please. This question is very difficult to understand from what you have provided.

Comment: Main edited, please look e-e

Comment: From what you showed, if I'm understanding correctly the following is likely easier and faster than messing with regex: loop through get 12 chars. Skip until you hit a non-0. Grab 12 chars. Repeat

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex with [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
yourHex.split(/0000(?!00)/g)
```

This is an explicit translation of your problem description. However it might not necessarily be what you want, because it yields (maybe) surprising results:

```
"10000001".split(/0000(?!00)/g)
// => ["10", "01"]
```

If you want the four zeroes to not be preceded by another zero, you might have to use another technique, since JS regexes do not support lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to split on "0000" but you want to leave "000000" alone?

SO for example, `"00001111000000222200003233"` would result in 
`["11110000002222","333"]`?

```
"00001111000000222200003333".replace(/000000/g,"token")
    .split("0000")
    .map(function (el) {
        return el.replace(/token/g,"000000"); 
        });
//["11110000002222","333"]
```

negative lookahead will yield a different result

```
"00001111000000222200003333".split(/0000(?!00)/)
//["", "11110", "02222", "3333"]
```

not sure what you are looking for exactly though

Answer (score -1):

I think your question need more explaining and maybe some code to back it up. I think this is what you are asking for.

```
yourHex.split(/0000/);
```